# Rails date_select turns into yesterdays date when submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with a datetime field

```
.form-group
   = f.label :sale_date, class: "col-sm-2 control-label"
   .col-sm-10
     = f.date_select :sale_date, class: "form-control", required: true
```

When I choose any date on the form and submit it in the console I see that it's actually submitting yesterdays date e.g if I chose todays date then I'd see

```
"sale"=>{"amount"=>"400", "new_sale"=>"0", "sale_date(1i)"=>"2015", "sale_date(2i)"=>"7", "sale_date(3i)"=>"31", "employee_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Create Sale"}

 (0.2ms)  SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "sales" ("amount", "employee_id", "sale_date", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["amount", 400], ["employee_id", 2], ["sale_date", "2015-07-30 23:00:00.000000"], ["created_at", "2015-07-31 10:23:58.551966"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-31 10:23:58.551966"]]
```

It's turning todays date, `31/07/2015` into `"2015-07-30 23:00:00.000000"`

I have no idea what's going on...

Comment: In which timezone your application is running? Are you in GMT+1

Comment: it is related to your time zone and field. if you want to save date only for sale_date you should use date field rather than datetime. bcoz that will return time as well. secondly there is some time zone which is being used when you are fetching the date. it is subtracting the hours as per time. check using `Time.zone.name`

Comment: I had set timezone to 'London', removing it fixed the problem, though surely London is the correct timezone for me If I live there?